# Eclipse PDE :: Test properties

Tags: xml-parsing, eclipse-plugin

The plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` declares a `commonFilter` element with the id `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot` to extend `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent`:

```
  <commonFilter
        id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot"
        name="%filters.startsWithDot.name"
        description="%filters.startsWithDot.description"
        activeByDefault="true"
        >
     <filterExpression>
        <and>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value=".*"/>
            </adapt>
        </and>
     </filterExpression>
  </commonFilter>
```

The element `<test>` has the property `org.eclipse.core.resources.name`. I browsed the view *Plug-in Registry* to find out what this property means (and why it's not simply named `name`) but all I could find are further property assignments.

Can someone explain me what `org.eclipse.core.resources.name` means, why it's not enough to just use `name` as a property, and which class actually processes this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value specified in the `test` `property` attribute is a value defined using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point.

In this particular case the declaration is in the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin:

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
       id="org.eclipse.core.resources.resourcePropertyTester"
       class="org.eclipse.core.internal.propertytester.ResourcePropertyTester"
       namespace="org.eclipse.core.resources"
       properties="name,path,extension,readOnly,projectNature,persistentProperty,projectPersistentProperty,sessionProperty,projectSessionProperty"
       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>
```

which defines a number of tests include the name test.

When you reference a property tester you must always specify the full name including the namespace - so it must be `org.eclipse.core.resources.name` and not just `name`, `org.eclipse.core.resources` is the namespace declared in the extension point. This is because there may be multiple property testers defined for `name` but each tester has a unique namespace so the full name is also unique.

`org.eclipse.core.resources.name` tests the resource name against a pattern. Any name starting with . in this case.